# RDLC paging issue

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I have a problem with a report that is very long. It has around 60 pages when it is in print layout, but it only shows me 1 of 1 page in normal layout. The report in normal layout is scrolling very slow and I think it keeps all 60 pages into one and he can't draw it quick enough.
 Any suggestion how to split in multiple pages while in normal layout without changing the print layout? (i do not have any grouping that I could use for page breaks and the number of rows / page is not fixed either)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found it. On tablix properties (right click on any row > Tablix properties) I had to uncheck "Keep together on one page if possible".