# Rdlc tablix is showing in single page

Tags: c#, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I have a rdlc report with tablix inside. When the report loaded, it shows the entire tablix in single even though it has thousands of records. Is there any way to spread the tablix across multiple page.

I have also tried the solution mentioned in the link [RDLC paging issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005696/rdlc-paging-issue) but still not working.

Thanks,

Elangovan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved by unchecking "Keep together on one page if possible" checkbox on all the parent container controls.